# Water/air mages making a ship move faster

Tags: magic, ships

In my world, water and air mages/wizards can control any instances of water or air. Moving water or air in one direction would not move the mage in the opposite direction.

Using this, what would be some ways that moving water or air, without moving a massive amount of water or air (for instance, an air mage cannot simply pick up a boat and make it fly, but instead they might be able to make the wind slightly stronger). What are some other things water or air mages could do to increase the speed of a boat without moving a massive amount of air or water?

Comment: Important point: do they move water & air relative to themselves, or relative to the earth? ie. if they stand on a raft and "push" nearby water away from themselves, are they also pushing themselves backwards? Or does the water move without exerting a equal-and-opposite force on the mage? This would have implications for the direction they would want to move water/air (with or against the direction of travel)

Comment: @Qami added that to my question to make it more clear, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: There is an episode of Avatar about this.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw I’m afraid I don’t watch much avatar, can you please explain what they did in that episode to make the boat move faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of things.

1:  **Surf boat.**  Move water to pile up under boat.  You have made a wave.  Boat falls down the front of water into lower water.  Repeat.   Cue [Ventures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rcvo4U33_L4).

2:  **Suck boat.**  Move air away from front of boat.  Low pressure air sucks boat forward.  Boat and air behind moves into relatively lower pressure region ahead.   I have already painted that name on your boat but I can change it if you can think of a better one which I doubt.  Maybe "Venture"?  Nah.

3:  **Sail boat.**  Air pushes sails; you may have heard of this one.  Good for if your mage is not great about showing up for work.

4:  **Drift boat.**  Moving water underneath pushes boat forward.  Yes, yes.

5:  **Hydroplane.**  Low pressure above wings (this boat has wings) provides lift and reduces drag; propulsion is thru one of the other methods.

6:  **Tornado boat.**  Tornado lifts boat and carries it thru the air.  Turn off tornado before reaching Oz.  Unless you intend to go to Oz.  Also watch out for sharks.

Comment: These all seem like great ideas, and a hydroplane seems like something that would be quite interesting to implement. I have a question though, how would you create a tornado without a fire mage? National Geographic says “ Tornadoes form when warm, humid air collides with cold, dry air. The denser cold air is pushed over the warm air, usually producing thunderstorms. The warm air rises through the colder air, causing an updraft. The updraft will begin to rotate if winds vary sharply in speed or direction.” Wouldn’t you need a fire mage to create the warm air needed for a tornado?

Comment: @Yay not necessarily, warm moist air occurs naturally at sea in the sun and usually creates waterspouts or hurricanes depending on intensity and weather conditions.

Comment: @Yay - all mass air movement is caused by temperature differentials.  A hurricane (or maybe El Nino?) is the most extreme example but tornadoes and gentle breezes are all caused by different temperature masses of air jostling around.  Why else would air move?  Your mage is using his power to replicate the movement of air masses that is usually caused by thermal differences.

Answer (score 2):

In the world of Nicklodeon's Avatar, a considerable portion of humanity is born with the power to control one element. The titular Avatar is a person who is able to control all four. The way they control elements is similar to what you describe in the question, though I suspect there may be important differences.

In Avatar: the Last Airbender (the animation, not the movie from hell), season one, episode fifteen, a boy undergoes a ritual of passage into adulthood - which involves driving a ship over jagged rocks. He is accompanied by his sister, a water mage, and the Avatar.

As they approach the jagged rocks, the Avatar uses air magic to push the sail forward and somewhat up, and the waterbending girl uses water magic to pull a lot of water under the boat, thus allowing it to sail over the rocks.

[Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kQBiW47z84). The magic starts a bit after 1:30. Granted, the girl does move a massive amount of water... but you could do a less massive version with a small boat.

Comment: So this would mostly be useful when trying to go over obstacles, or by using a wave to push yourself forward? (Or did I misinterpret the video)

Comment: @Yay you can use it both ways. In another episode they use this kind of magic to move sandboats over desert sand, by pushing the sail forward.